# Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I am creating app using React-Native and testing it on Android device. ***After adding react-native-camera module***, the following error occurs:

`org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.` at "Build->Run Tasks" (Android Studio).

Concerning the Java compiler, there are about 20-30 errors, all of which show the following: `error: package android.support.annotation does not exist`, `error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist`, `error: package android.support.media does not exist`, etc.
OR `error: cannot find symbol class SparseArrayCompat`, `error: package Pools does not exist`, `error: cannot find symbol variable ExifInterface`, which when checked in the error file has to do with `import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;`-import kind of statements.

My android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        /*maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            //url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }*/
        google()
    }
}

tasks.withType(Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "4.10.1"
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

My app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
        implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
        implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
            force = true
        }
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation ('com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.3')
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    //implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
}
```

*My attempt at solution:*

- I added android-support-v4.jar file to the ./libs folder.
- I added "google()" or maven links to the dependencies.
- I tried changing minSdkVersion, compileVersion, etc, didn't help, *but
  I guess this might be the main problem.*
- Rebuilding the project didn't work too.
- Migrating project to Android X.

My SDK version: 28

Gradle version: 4.10.1

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' (Downgrading gradle version to 3.1.0 didn't work).

Answer (score 2):

change the minsdk version and compilesdk version in react-native-camera build.gradle file with your app build gradle properties.

### android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 16
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 28
      supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
      googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // or set latest version
      androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
}
```

### react-native-camera/android/build.gradle

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 28
   buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName computeVersionName()
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in the root directory:

```
npx jetify
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently due to [react-native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210), i am getting error in all my working projects. My react native version is 0.61.5

with reference to

> **Fix for older react-native (< 0.63)**:
> The fix above only works on gradle 6.2 and higher. Older react-native used older gradle.

i just change my gradle version to 6.2 from 5.5. It worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Checkout platform specific requirements... For example on android check permissions which should at least be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```